# C# 8 base interface's default method invocation workaround

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, c#-8.0

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods 
It is possible to explicitly invoke an interface base implementation with the following syntax.

```
base(IInterfaceType).Method();
```

But this doesn't seem to be implemented yet.

Is there a workaround (e.g reflection) to achieve this?

---

> Example code to illustrate the problem

```
interface IA
{
    void M()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IA.M");
    }
}

interface IB : IA
{
    void IA.M()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IB.M");
    }
}

interface IC : IA
{
    void IA.M()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IC.M");
    }
}

class D : IA, IB, IC
{
    public void M()
    {
        // base(IB).M(); Is not yet supported apparently
        ((IB)this).M(); // Throws stack overflow
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        D d = new D();
        d.M();
    }
}
```

Comment: You linked to a *proposal* document. In C# 8 it's not possible to call a base method, period. ` ((IB)this).M();` is the explicit invocation syntax used to call the actual implementation of the method, so the stack overflow is expected. Essentially, this is a `M(){ M();}`

Comment: It's not a matter of "not implemented yet" in C# 8. as this version is final. Base invocation *may* appear in later version or not.

Comment: No, there is no workaround (without taking a dependency on compiler internals, that is, which I wouldn't consider a valid workaround). There is a clear need for this and it was originally scheduled to be part of C# 8, but it proved too ambitious. This proposal is slated for implementation in C# 9, though that's subject to change. Until then, this can't be done except by making the methods available under other names/different scopes.

Comment: Why are you looking for base invocation anyway? There are probably other ways to do whatever you want to do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The link in the question points to a version of the proposal copied [from the proposal document in Github](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods.md)

The feature was [cut in April 2019](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/6b5a397cc4faef6d481d9bace13d7e3c19de63bb/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-04-29.md)

> **Conclusion**
>
> Cut base() syntax for C# 8. We intend to bring this back in the next major release.

The design meeting doc explains that without runtime support (which wouldn't be available in time), the implementation would be workable at best for C# but not VB.NET.

> If B.M is not present at run time, A.M() will be called. For base() and interfaces, this is not supported by the runtime, so the call will throw an exception instead. We'd like to add support for this in the runtime, but it is too expensive to make this release.
>
> We have some workarounds, but they do not have the behavior we want, and are not the preferred codegen. Our implementation for C# is somewhat workable, although not exactly what we would like, but the VB implementation would be much more difficult. Moreover, the implementation for VB would require the interface implementation methods to be public API surface.

As for the infinite recursion, this

```
public void M()
{
    ((IB)this).M(); // Throws stack overflow
}
```

That's essentially

```
public void M()
{
    M(); // Throws stack overflow
}
```

Default interface members are called the same way explicitly implemented interface methods are, through the interface. Besides, you're asking to call the method on `this`, not `base`.

Comment: I got it working using  MethodInfo.GetFunctionPointer(); but it turned out a bit messy

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround. 
I got it working, using `GetFunctionPointer`

> **Warning** do not use this code

```
static class BaseInterfaceInvocationExtension
{
    private static readonly string invalidExpressionMessage = "Invalid expression.";

    public static void Base<TInterface>(this TInterface owner, Expression<Action<TInterface>> selector)
    {
        if (selector.Body is MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
        {
            MethodInfo methodInfo = methodCallExpression.Method;
            string name = methodInfo.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + methodInfo.Name;
            Type type = owner.GetType();
            InterfaceMapping interfaceMapping = type.GetInterfaceMap(typeof(TInterface));
            var map = interfaceMapping;
            var interfaceMethod = map.InterfaceMethods.First(info =>
                info.Name == name);
            var functionPointer = interfaceMethod.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();

            var x = methodCallExpression.Arguments.Select(expression =>
            {
                if (expression is ConstantExpression constantExpression)
                {
                    return constantExpression.Value;
                }
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(expression, expression.Type));
                return lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
            }).ToArray();
            Type actionType = null;
            if (x.Length == 0)
            {
                actionType = typeof(Action);
            }else if (x.Length == 1)
            {
                actionType = typeof(Action<>);
            }
            else if (x.Length == 2)
            {
                actionType = typeof(Action<,>);
            }
            var genericType = actionType.MakeGenericType(methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(t => t.ParameterType).ToArray());
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType, owner, functionPointer);
            instance.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke").Invoke(instance, x);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(invalidExpressionMessage);
        }
    }
}

class D : IA, IB, IC
{
    public void M(int test)
    {
       this.Base<IB>(d => d.M(test));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        D d = new D();
        d.M(12);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround. It isn't ideal. Perhaps it will help someone.

```
class C : IB
{
    public void IBM() => (this as IB).M();
}

class D : IA, IB, IC
{
    private C _c = new C();

    public void M()
    {
        _c.IBM();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this could work:

```cs
...
interface IB : IA
{
    void IA.M()
    {
        IB_M();
    }
  
    void IB_M()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IB.M");
    }
}
...

class D : IA, IB, IC
{
    public void M()
    {
        (this as IB).IB_M();
    }
}
```

Not ideal either but less verbose.