# Is there no way to call the default interface method in an implementing class?

Tags: c#, default-interface-member

Consider this interface and class implementer

```
interface I
{
   string M() => "I.M()";
}

class C: I
{
   public string M()=>???.Replace("I","C");
}
```

Instead of `???` what is the way to invoke the default method? I've tried `base.M()`, but it wasn't a fan. And I've also tried `base(I).M()` and that didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# 8 base interface's default method invocation workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59398027/c-sharp-8-base-interfaces-default-method-invocation-workaround)

Comment: The default implementation is there so you don't have to do anything with it. Clients can just do `new C().M();` If you want to *change* the implementation, you're free to do that also.