# C# How to reference default interface implementation in implementer class

Tags: c#, interface, default-implementation

Consider the following interface, with a default implementation of `TestMethod`

```c#
public interface TestInterface
{
    public int TestMethod()
    {
        return 15;
    }
}
```

Calling `TestMethod` in the following class will cause a StackOverflowException:

```c#
public class TestClass : TestInterface
{
    public int TestMethod()
    {
        return 1 + (this as TestInterface).TestMethod();
    }
}
```

Now I understand why this is, but is there any way to get around it? Something like `base.TestMethod()` for referencing one of the class's implemented interfaces?

I know I could rename the method in TestInterface and reference it in TestClass that way, but that would cause problems for other classes that don't need to reference the default implementation.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59398027/c-sharp-8-base-interfaces-default-method-invocation-workaround

Answer (score -1):

you need to use "public override" to do what you are asking.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer with a concrete code snippet and more description.